# How "wide" or "far" is a google coordinate?

Tags: google-maps

If I have the following coordinates obtained from the Google API:

```
[longitude] => 18.12288
[latitude]  => -23.1233399
```

I want to know how accurate this coordinate is. In other words, what area does this specific coordinate cover? Is it a 1 meter by 1 meter area, or is it less accurate and maybe cover a 50 by 50 meter area? How do you calculate the area it covers?

*UPDATE*

Using [this](http://rechneronline.de/geo-coordinates/) calculator, I could get:

```
0.000001 = .1 meter
0.00001  = 1 meter
0.0001   = 11 meters
0.001    = 111 meters
0.01     = 1113 meters  / 1.1 km
0.1      = 11132 meters / 11.1 km
1.0      = 111319 meters / 111 km
```

Is this correct?

Comment: How would you decide that a coordinate `1` is less accurate than `1.1` ? When the original coordinate was `1` a returned coordinate `1` will have a higher accuracy than  original coordinate:`1.12` returned:`1.1` . You'll have to know the original coordinate to be able to determine the accuracy

Comment: Which Google API are you using to retrieve that coordinate?

Comment: I'm using Business Maps API. And basically this question boils down to what is the difference between two points, if the coordinate difference is 0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001, and so on. Also, can't imagine why this got downvoted...

Answer (score 1):

you can work it out here

http://www.csgnetwork.com/gpscoordconv.html

Coords are usually meter accurate if the seconds are well defined.

Apparently i neeed more rep to comment, anyhow,

No, your last comment is wrong.

coords are usually pim point accurate assuming you have seconds included in your coord.

To work out standard coordinates

xx.xxxxxxxxx
the first two numbers are your degrees
so it will look like this "xx" and "xxxxxxx" for the remainder,
to get minutes, you divide the remainder by 60,
it looks like this now "xx" "xx" "xxxxx"
 and what is the decimal of that equation is again divided by 60, to get your seconds.
you may be left with decimals after you work out seconds, but those are fine, the more numbers you have, the more accurate your coord will be.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The length of a degree in a a projected system (2d system such as the one used by Google Maps) depends on the latitude.  Using [this simple calculator](http://www.csgnetwork.com/degreelenllavcalc.html), you can see that if you change the latitude from 0 degrees to 90 degrees (Equator to North Pole), you get a different length (by up to a kilometer - 110km at North Pole vs 111km at Equator).

Wikipedia has a good summary of the [lengths at the equator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees) and those match the ones you typed out.  Based on the lat/long that you provided, the accuracy would be around 1 meter.